# How to set/get values using the automatic options of VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setter, getter

Today I found out that VS offers an automatic way to define `setters` and `getters`. To make it crystal clear I have a simple class `Students`:

```
 class Students
    {
        private string name;
        private Int32 pin;
        private string addres;
        private int phone;
     ...
```

And when I select `name` and click <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd> then select `C#` and then `propg` I get:

```
   class Students
    {
        private string public int MyProperty { get; private set; }
        private Int32 pin;
        private string addres;
        private int phone;
```

There is obviously a problem with the code like this so I end up with :

```
   class Students
    {
        private string name { get; private set; }
        private Int32 pin;
        private string addres;
        private int phone;
```

My question is - is this the right way to get advantage of the VS automisation for `getters` and `setters`? What is the right syntax for setting and getting the value of `name`? If this code is correct is there a more elegant way to use VS to create my `getters` and `setters` instead of the one I found out?

Comment: Before deciding on the correct usage (private field, private property, public property, etc.) you first need to define how the value itself will be used.  Take `name` in your class for example.  Does it need to be visible external to the class?  Does it need to be settable external to the class?  Is there business logic to be used in getting/setting it?  How is it used?

Comment: please note that automatic properties are inherent to C# and not a concept of Visual Studio. It just happens to provide a feature for generating them.

Comment: A couple random tips: 1) C# naming conventions suggest capitalizing properties, so you'd use `Name` instead of `name`. 2) You don't need to specify `private` twice.  It only needs to be specified on the setter if the getting is otherwise `public` or `protected`, etc. 3) Why is your class name pluralized? The class' data members suggest a single Student, but the class is called `Students`. This seems very unintuitive.

Comment: Strange. I never used VS for that. I am using JetBrains ReSharper plug-in and it does it correctly and intuitively - http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Generation__Properties.html

Comment: @David thanks a lot, I still underestimate the conventions, I know it's bad habbit, thanks for pointing this out for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind automatic properties is to remove the private fields entirely, and replace them with automatic properties (which have a hidden backing field).

There's also a code snippet

```
prop (TAB TAB)
```

That said, you should consider making get / setters public, and the usual convention is to PascalCase property names, viz.

```
class Students
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 Pin { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
   ...
```

**EDIT**
As per Servy's comment, there is a growing movement toward making data-centric classes like DTO's [immutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383979%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). This would result in making the setters private, and providing an initialization constructor and / or class factory method to the class. But that is something for later :)

Comment: Having private setters is quite common.  I wouldn't discourage people from using them in general.  I't often pretty clear whether they should be publicly settable or not.

Answer (score 7):

Put your cursor over your private variable declaration, and press  `ctrl-R`, `ctrl-E`

Comment: Thanks, it's really easy withi these shortcuts, but because of the shrot syntax I think I'll ry to use `prop (TAB TAB)` but really useful shrotcuts though. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not. What you need is *refactoring* from field to automatic property, not *new property*.

Answer (score 4):

You can type "prop", press TAB twice, and Visual Studio will add:

```
public TYPE Type { get; set; }
```

Then you change "TYPE" and "Type"

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

That's the quickest shortcut for creating properties in Visual Studio.

EDIT: Also, as Serg mentioned you can go to the `Refactor` -> `Encapsulate Field` menu option to convert your fields to properties.

Answer (score 2):

Your resulting syntax is correct... if you want a private getter/setter with an [automatic backing field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

`Ctrl +r,e` will encapsulate your field in a property, meaning it will auto-generate a `public` property with getters/setters for your `private` field.  For exmaple:

Starting with your base class:

```
class Students
{
    private string name;
    private Int32 pin;
    private string addres;
    private int phone;
```

Select name and click `ctrl +r,e` then type the name to use for your new property (I used the suggested 'Name') and hit enter.  you should get the following output:

```
class Students
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    private Int32 pin;
    private string addres;
    private int phone;
```